# Promises and accessing this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions:

```
p.test = 'test';

p.functionA = function(){

    console.log('function A');
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();

    setInterval(function(){dfd.resolve();}, 2000);

    return dfd.promise();

};


p.functionB = function(){

    console.log('function B');
    console.log(this.test);
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();

    setInterval(function(){dfd.resolve();}, 2000);

    return dfd.promise();
};
```

The functions are called like so:

```
this.functionA().then(this.functionB);
```

I wish to get the value of test in function B yet it is undefined. Why? How can I access it?

Comment: `this.functionA().then(this.functionB.bind( this ) );`

Comment: If I have a number of .then() will I need to bind each time eg. this.functionA().then(this.functionB.bind(this)).then(this.functionC.bind(this)).then(this.functionD.bind(this));

Answer (score 3):

You can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the context to the function:

```
this.functionA().then( this.functionB.bind( this ) );
```

If you want to support IE8 and don't want to use the [bind polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Polyfill), you can also use [jQuery's proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
this.functionA().then( $.proxy( this.functionB, this ) );
```

If you don't want to keep repeating this, you could also use a more complete Promise library, like [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md). You would need to update your return values to return a trusted promise:

```
return Promise.resolve( dfd.promise() ).
```

Then you could use:

```
Promise.bind(this).then( this.functionA ).then( this.functionB ). ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [`deferred.resolveWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/)

```js
var p = {};

p.test = 'test';

p.functionA = function() {

  console.log('function A');
  var dfd = new $.Deferred();

  setTimeout(function() {
    // set context : `this` of returned jQuery promise to `p`
    dfd.resolveWith(p);
  }, 2000);

  return dfd.promise();

};


p.functionB = function() {
  // `this`: `p`
  console.log('function B');
  console.log(this.test);
  var dfd = new $.Deferred();

  setTimeout(function() {
    dfd.resolve();
  }, 2000);

  return dfd.promise();
};

p.functionA().then(p.functionB);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```